# Как узнать имя одного из подкатологов Python?

Tags: python

Скрипт python условно лежит в c:\Scripts

Структура-

```
C:
-Scripts
--pythonscript.py
--content
----dfg45dfg(ЭТО НУЖНАЯ Папка имеет какое-то такое название и оно всегда разное)
----shared(эта папка всегда имеет такое название)
```

Как мне находить папку с постоянно изменным названием в подкатологе?

Comment: Методом исключения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой кусочек:

```
import os

path = './content'
for entry in os.listdir(path):
    # Файлы - игнорируем
    if os.path.isfile(path + '/' + entry): continue
    # Если имя подкаталога не shared, значит он нам подходит
    if not entry == 'shared': break
else:
    entry = "Каталог не найден"

print(entry)
```

Он будет выводить первый найденный подкаталог в каталоге './content' с именем, отличным от `shared`. Если такой каталог не найден, то он выведет сообщение об этом.

### Добавлено

Я несколько переделал код, чтобы он игнорировал возможные файлы в каталоге `./content`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @chrispsow Пожалуйста! И ловите небольшое изменение, чтоб работало правильно, если в каталоге ещё окажутся и файлы